# Get Access Token with REST API in flutter/dart

Tags: rest, http, dart, flutter, localhost

I cannot take access token with this getData() function, it return "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname". How can ı fix this problem ? Am ı change Future<> method, async or http methods ?

Here is my main.dart :

```
Future<HttpClient> getData() async {

  Map<String, String> connection = {
    'grant_type': 'string',
    'branchcode': 'string',
    'password': 'string',
    'username': 'string',
    'dbname': 'string',
    'dbuser': 'string',
    'dbpassword': 'string',
    'dbtype': 'string+'
  };

  var uri = Uri.http("192.168.1.44:7070","api/v2/token",connection);
  http.Response r = await http.get(uri);
  print(r.statusCode);
  print(r.body);
}
```

ERROR !

```
I/flutter ( 9316): 400
I/flutter ( 9316): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
I/flutter ( 9316): <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
I/flutter ( 9316): <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
I/flutter ( 9316): <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
I/flutter ( 9316): <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
I/flutter ( 9316): </BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: That error is being returned by the server, so you need to investigate there to see what it doesn't like. (Previously, your C# code was sending the `connection` parameters as URL encoded body, but it might also work to send them as query parameters.) I'd suggest using something like Postman or another working client to prove that the request works, then compare the difference between the request you are forming in Dart and the working request. (As you are just at the stage of testing the request, consider just using a Dart program to test; you can iterate quickly using a simple cmd line prog.)

Comment: I can do it in c# easily

Comment: In which case you can easily compare the HTTP request sent by Dart and that sent by C#. Once you see the difference you should be able to adapt the Dart code to match. If you can't, that will be a good question.

Comment: I don't now how ı can compare this two language ?

Comment: I'd suggest using a packet capture tool like Wireshark to capture the request and response.

Comment: I was tried with Postman. I was entered the query parameters which is my connection map. But it returns unsported_grant_type error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get token from rest api you have to post your connection with **http.post()** method.In this method you can easily declare the connection string in **body** field.I tried and it is working.

**Here is my code block:**

```
   Future<Null> getData() async {

        var url = "http://192.168.1.23:7070/api/v2/token";
        http.post(url, body:{
          "grant_type": "string",
          "branchcode": "string",
          "password": "string",
          "username": "string",
          "dbname": "string",
          "dbuser": "string",
          "dbpassword": "string",
          "dbtype": "string"
        }).then((response){
          print("Response Status: ${response.statusCode}");
          print("Response Body: ${response.body}");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get the access token using unsplash api and it worked fine. I have used two plugins. first one, [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher), it allows you to open the url in a browser. you should put the registration url and once the user has successfully registered, user is redirected to your app. how? using the second plugin [uni_links](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uni_links). once the user return back you start to extract the access token.

**Launch the url that allow user to register**

```
_launchURL() async {
    var registerUrl= Constants.registerUrl;
    if (await canLaunch(registerUrl)) {
      await launch(registerUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $loginUrl';
    }
  }
```

when the user finish the process. your app should listen for this step

```
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initUniLinks();
  }




Future<Null> initUniLinks() async {
    getUriLinksStream().listen((Uri uri) {
      if (uri != null) {
        setState(() {
          String code = uri.queryParameters["code"];
          print("code:" + code);
          if (code != null) {
            _getAccessToken(Constants.clientId, Constants.clientSecret,
                Constants.redirectURI, code, "authorization_code");
          }
        });
      }
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("error:" + err.toString());
    });
  }



_getAccessToken(String client_id, String client_secret, String redirect_uri,
      String code, String grant_type) async {
    var url = "https://unsplash.com/oauth/token";

    var query_params = {
      "client_id": client_id,
      "client_secret": client_secret,
      "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
      "code": code,
      "grant_type": grant_type
    };

    var response = await http.post(url, body: query_params);

    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    var accessToken = AccessToken.fromJson(map);
    _saveAccessTokenToPrefs(accessToken);
  }
```

Comment: ı cannot do that easily. ı take all at of warnings when ı mixed with my codes.